# maxRequestLength+maxAllowedContentLength+HTTPS not working

Tags: asp.net, azure, iis, web-applications, web-config

I have made a service that i host on an azure webapp. This will be used to upload files. IIS has a built in security feature that limits the file upload size.

To work around this i have put the following in my web.config

```
<system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="80000000" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
...
    <system.web>
       <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="80000" targetFramework="4.5.2" executionTimeout="9000" />
    </system.web>
```

This is however not working for me. As soon as i upload a large file (50mb for example) it hits me with a 404. When i upload a smaller file (10mb) it works fine. The service is a soap and is called over https. The call does not time out, the exception occurs within 5 seks of the call being made, my guess is it uploads 30mb and then it thinks it is under attack and aborts.

Am i missing something here?

Answer (score 2):

You can go to folder:

%windir%\system32\inetsrv\

run command:

```
appcmd set config -section:requestFiltering -requestLimits.maxAllowedContentLength:80000000
```

or if you only want to set it for your app, run this:

```
appcmd set config "Default Web Site/" -section:requestFiltering -requestLimits.maxAllowedContentLength:80000000
```

also you need to update overrideModeDefault to 'Allow' in web.config:

```
<section name="requestFiltering" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
```

Then you can have your web.config updated with appcmd.exe

Hope [this article](https://forums.iis.net/t/1066272.aspx) and [this article](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/requestlimits) will help you.

About how to use appcmd.exe, you can see https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772200%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

After that deploy your project to azure webapp and try again.

Answer (score 0):

I did that configuration, but i fixed my problem putting on my ControllerBase something like:

```
        protected override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
    {

        base.OnResultExecuting(filterContext);

        if(filterContext.Result.GetType().Name == "JsonResult")
            filterContext.Result.GetType().GetProperty("MaxJsonLength").SetValue(filterContext.Result, int.MaxValue);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For **classic ASP** users also check this settings in addition to the web.config settigns:

IIS > CLick on Website > ASP > Limit Properties > Maximum request entity body limit

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was because the configuration of httpProtocol in the web.config file had the 'allowKeepAlive' in false.

```
 <httpProtocol allowKeepAlive="false">
```

I deleted the `allowKeepAlive="false"` (making it uses the default value of true) and all worked with big files (configuring the 'maxrequestlength' and 'maxallowedcontentlength')